# How can i implement JWT authentication C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I tried to apply a jwt generator in C # asp.net core mvc project. I can create the jwt token and use it for the login site. But looking at jwt instances I get confused and i am not sure my work is the best practice for jwt. Here is my code;

This JwtHandler take tokenoptions class and claims then generate token

```
   public static class JwtHandler
{
    public static TokenOptions TokenOptions { get; set; }

    public static OperationResult<string> GenerateToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        OperationResult<string> result = new();

        if (TokenOptions == null)
        {
            result.Messages = "Token Options cannot be null."));
            result.IsSuccess = false;

            return result;
        }

        SymmetricSecurityKey secretKey = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TokenOptions.SecretKey));

        SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        JwtSecurityToken jwt = new
                               (
                                    issuer: TokenOptions.Issuer,
                                    audience: TokenOptions.Audience,
                                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(TokenOptions.TokenExpirationInMinutes),
                                    notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                                    claims: claims,
                                    signingCredentials: signingCredentials
                               );

        result.Data = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

        return result;
    }}
```

Tokenoptions.cs

```
 public class TokenOptions
{
    public string Audience { get; set; }

    public string Issuer { get; set; }

    public int TokenExpirationInMinutes { get; set; }

    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie(c =>
                           {
                               c.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
                               c.LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout");
                           })
                .AddCustomJwtBearer(Configuration);
```

CustomJwtBearer

```
public static void AddCustomJwtBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        TokenOptions tokenOptions = configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();

        JwtHandler.TokenOptions = tokenOptions;

        builder.AddJwtBearer(c =>
                             {
                                 c.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                 {
                                     ValidateIssuer = true,
                                     ValidateAudience = true,
                                     ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                                     ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                     IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenOptions.SecretKey))
                                 };
                             });
    }
```

And here is the method that i call jwthandler

```
    [HttpPost("/token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TokenGenerate([FromBody] UserModel userModel)
    {
        OperationResult<User> userResult = await _userService.LoginAsync(userModel.EmailAddress, userModel.Password);

        if (!userResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            return BadRequest(userResult);
        }

        List<Claim> claims = new()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userResult.Data.EmailAddress),
            new Claim("FullName", userResult.Data.FirstName + " " + userResult.Data.LastName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator")
        };

        OperationResult<string> tokenResult = JwtHandler.GenerateToken(claims);

        return Json(tokenResult);
    }
```

So i wonder my way is the best practice for jwt generator or which way is the best for it?
And one more thing, i see some people use httpcontext for jwt token so i wonder when i should use httpcontext for jwt, why people use it?

Comment: I think the better practice would be using something like IdentityServer4 or Keycloack. You'll be better off both security-wise and time-spent-wise using something that will generate tokens for you so you could focus on the business logic instead.

Comment: I implemented that version with deleted statics and use an interface for handler. I don't use IdentityServer or Keylock because i tried learn this "generate token and set claims" business but thank you for answer. I will try your suggestion as soon as possible. @MichalRosenbaum